# Testing deleteAll() from repository with delete method rest api with MockMvc

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, integration-testing

I am doing the integration tests on a REST api where all the tests work but this one.

```
@Test
public void deleteAllUsers_should_return_noContent() throws Exception {
    //Given
    //When
    ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc
            .perform(delete("/pair?delAll"));
    //Then
    resultActions
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isNoContent());
}
```

I am expecting a 204 http status but it gets a 400. Here is the code for the method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pair", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, params = "delAll")
public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteAllUsers() {
    userRepository.deleteAll();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

Any ideas to what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Found the solution just adding "=true" to these lines

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pair", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, params = "delAll=true")

ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc
            .perform(delete("/pair?delAll=true"));
```